# How can I extract an embedded archive to disk during the installation process

Tags: inno-setup

I have an embedded `7Zip archive` in my setup script.
Is there a "native" way of extracting the contents to a target folder?
If not any hints on how this could be achieved?

Updated with my implementation. Thanks for the hint TLama

```
[Files]    
Source: "Documentation.7zip"; DestDir: "{tmp}"    
Source: "7za.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\7za.exe"; Parameters: "x -o""{app}"" ""{tmp}\Documentation.7zip""";     Flags: runhidden; Description: "{cm:InstallingDocumentation}"; StatusMsg: "{cm:InstallingDocumentationStatus}"

[CustomMessages]
en.InstallingDocumentation=Documentation Files
en.InstallingDocumentationStatus=Installing Documentation Files. This may take several minutes...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no native way to extract 7zip files from InnoSetup installer. However, you can get a copy of 7zip library, [`which is redistributable`](http://www.7-zip.org/license.txt) and call it from InnoSetup script's code section.

Comment: You're welcome! Though I was thinking about 7z.dll and its importing to the InnoSetup script code, that might work too. If I were having time I would translate the imports to InnoSetup, but I'm really busy now...

Comment: Do you think its more efficient with the imports and script?

Comment: It's not about efficiency, since 7za.exe will most probably call the very same code of the 7z.dll inside. The difference is that with 7z.dll you could handle errors, what you can't with your current script using 7za.exe.

Answer (score 3):

Inno doesn't have any native method of extracting files from anything other than it's own archives (which normally compress better than 7Zip).

Inno Setup can however use wildcards for including files to install:

```
[Files]
Source: "Documentation\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}/Documentation/";
```

If you have many small files, using the `solidcompression` flag will improve compression performance and size.

Comment: I think this question asks how to extract standalone 7zip file (maybe distibuted as 7zip by a third party vendor) included in the package during setup. Though unpacking it and including to the package might be workaround. [+1]

Comment: That was the original Code. But there are more than 5000 files in the Documentation. And adding them during the compiler run is quite inefficient.

Comment: @TobiasR See my comment about `solidcompression`.

Comment: Yes, recompressing the files during the compile is slightly more inefficient than having them pre-compressed.  But this cost is paid only once per software version, while the cost of separately extracting the files is paid for every user of your software.  (Not the least of which is that it will not get uninstalled by default.)  Just set up a proper build environment for your software (eg. automated build scripts) and it won't matter that it takes slightly longer to build.